# Equivalent of matlabs interp2 spline in scipy/numpy

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, scipy

I am currently converting our matlab code base to python 3.5 with scipy/numpy.

The line i am currently struggling with contains the [interp2 function with spline](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp2.html?refresh=true#inputarg_method) as the method. I generally am able to find the counterpart in the world of scipy, but the description of the spline method is too much for me

> The interpolation is based on a cubic spline using not-a-knot end conditions.

What interpolate method from scipy/numpy should I use to get the same effect?

Comment: Off the top of my head, have you looked at `scipy.interpolate.interp2d`?

Comment: Yes, but the only methods parameter that function takes are 'linear', probably not what I want, 'cubic', again not what I want, and 'quintic', which I don't want either - I think.

Comment: The [scipy interpolation documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/interpolate.html) has many spline options.

Comment: So...what makes you think that's not what you're looking for? And did I miss it in your question *what* you're exactly looking for? Have you tried to see if it does what you're looking for?

Comment: Yeah. I tried cubic and it doesn't do the same as the matlab spline, quintic didn't even let me input my values ( dfitpack.error: (my>ky) failed for hidden my: regrid_smth:my=4 ).

Comment: And does it give a *correct* result, if not the exact same? Is it well-defined *what kind* of spline you have to use?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest [splrep](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.splrep.html#scipy.interpolate.splrep) . `scipy.interpolate.splrep(x,y,k=3,task=-1)` seems to do the same job. `interp2d` is a wrapper with less parameters.

Comment: Thank you, although I don't know how to use splrep. I don't know what "knots" are or what a 'order of the spline fit' is and splrep seems to want only two axis, but I need three ( hence interp2, not interp1). I am sure this function is doing what I want to do, but I don't know how to mangle my parameters into this function.

Comment: @Nozdrum I'd wager [`bisplrep`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.bisplrep.html#scipy.interpolate.bisplrep) is the same for 2d.